# Return types and arguments of interfaces and lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm trying to write a function in three classes that will compare two lists of objects of that same class.

**General Idea**

```
List<Toads> aTList = ...
List<Toads> bTList = ...
List<Toads> tResult = compare(aTList , bTList ); 

List<Frogs> aFList = ...
List<Frogs> bFList = ...
List<Frogs> fResult = compare(aFList , bFList );
```

*Note: `Toad` and `Frog` can both extend a interface that provides necessary funcitons to compare*

The issue is that after comparing I would like to use the returned lists (`tResult` and `fResult`) with their specific type (`Toad` and `Frog`).

I tried something like specified here [Java interfaces and return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types/2413874#2413874), but I couldn't get all the types to line up.

I also tried using things like `<? extends Amphibian>` as the parameter and return type to `compare`, but then the returned type is `Amphibian`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public <T extends Amphibian> List<T> compare(List<T> a, List<T> b);`

Comment: I'm giving pickypg the check because he was first

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something this is what you're looking for?

```
public class AmphibianComparer<T extends Amphibian> {
  public List<T> compare(List<T> listOne, List<T> listTwo) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually give the signature for `compare`. Is this what you want?

`<T extends YourInterface> T compare(List<T>, List<T>)`

Comment: I didn't give the signature, because I didn't know what it should be ;) Your answer was exactly it, but pickypg is a ninja

Comment: You didn't know exactly what it should be, of course. But there are other variations on the method signature pickypg and I used - which to me was the most obvious - that also would have fulfilled the code snippet you did provided. It usually helps to show what you've tried so far. In this case, it wasn't necessary. Glad you got things working!

Comment: I agree that I could have been more specific. I was actually hoping that by not giving anything specific I wouldn't stop someone from giving me something completely new. I didn't want to taint the brilliance of others with my ignorance as it were.