# Java complains I haven't implemented a method

Tags: java

I have the following interface:

```
interface IBasicListNode<T> {
  /**
   * Returns the current element
   */
  public T getElement();

  /**
   * Gets the next ListNode. Returns null if theres no next element
   */
  public IBasicListNode<T> getNext();

  /**
   * Sets the next ListNode 
   */
  public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node);
}
```

And a class:

```
class BasicListNode<T> implements IBasicListNode<T> {
  protected T _elem;
  protected BasicListNode<T> _next;

  public T getElement() {
    return this._elem;
  }

  public BasicListNode<T> getNext() {
    return this._next;
  }

  public void setNext(BasicListNode<T> node) {
    this._next = node;
  }

  /**
   * Transverse through ListNodes until getNext() returns null
   */ 
  public BasicListNode<T> getLast() {
    BasicListNode<T> tmp = this;
    while (tmp != null) {
      tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }
    return tmp;
  }
}
```

And I got the folloeing error:

```
jiewmeng@JM-PC:/labs/Uni/CS1020/Lab/03/prob 2/LinkedList$ javac BasicListNode.java 
BasicListNode.java:1: BasicListNode is not abstract and does not override 
abstract method setNext(IBasicListNode<T>) in IBasicListNode

class BasicListNode<T> implements IBasicListNode<T> {
^
```

Why isn't java detecting that `BasicListNode<T> implements IBasicListNode<T>`?

Comment: Note that the signature for your setNext method is different in the super and in the concrete class, so you´re not overriding it.

Comment: @Yar, I updated the Interface & Error , it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to implement the method:

```
public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node);
```

Note the type of the parameter `node` is in fact `IBasicListNode<T>` and not simply `BasicListNode<T>`.

Take a look at the way `ArrayList` is implemented ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). It implements the `Collection` interface. Yet there is no `addAll(ArrayList<T> list)` method. Instead it must implement the `Collection` interface and thus it must implement a `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` method.

In you example you want to change your interface to read as follows:

```
public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node);
```

Then implement the method in your `BasicListNode` class as follows:

```
public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node) {
    this._next = node;
}
```

***Note:** Your `_next` variable must now be of type `IBasicListNode<T>` or you must some how check for and cast to `BasicListNode`.

**EDIT:** 
To be clear `ArrayList` could in fact contain a method called `addAll(ArrayList<T> list)` if it wanted to but that is optional. However, it absolutely must contain a method called `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` in order to fully implement the `Collection` interface.

The take away of the story is that when implementing an interface your class must contain a method signature that is identical to the interface it is implementing. That is it must have the same return type, the same method name and the parameter list must have the same types and order.

**EDIT 2:**
To use `instanceof` with generics you will need to use the wildcard `<?>` as follows:

```
if(node instanceof BasicListNode<?>) {
    this._next = (BasicListNode<T>)node;
}
```

This is needed as `<T>` is not a type that can be checked against at compile time since you don't know what type will be used at runtime. The `<?>` allows you accept a `BasicListNode` of any type generic.

As to why the `getNext()` method works despite having a slightly different return type has to do with the power of generics. There are a lot of special cases when using generics and requires a little more time to understand it all. For more details I would recommend looking up generics and perhaps taking a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types/2413909#2413909). The accepted answer will only make things a little more confusing so I recommend taking a look at the second answer provided by Cam

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. But could you elaborate how is `? extends E` used?

Comment: @jiewmeng `<? extends E>` is used to allow a generic type to be any object that is a subclass of E. As an example, consider a method called `draw(ArrayList<? extends Shape> shape)` that draws any shape that extends the `Shape` class. Using the `<? extends Shape>` wildcard you could pass it an ArrayList containing a `Circle`, `Rectangle` or any other shape as long as it extends the `Shape` class.

Comment: I am wondering, if is it better design that my class stick with allowing `IBasicListNode<T>` instead of say expect `BasicListNode<T>` (for arguments) if my function only needs to work with methods defined in `IBasicListNode<T>`? Then what about return? Should I always return a more specific type so there will be room to cast it to a more generic type?

Comment: It appears confusing if my method signature shows I expects a `IBasicListNode` and throws an exception saying I require a `BasicListNode`. I found that if I use IBasicListNode in my implementation, I will encounter problems/confusion if I require functionality in `BasicListNode`

Answer (score 3):

your `setnext()` in the interface class should be

`public void setNext(BasicListNode<T> node);`

Its missing the argument that's implemented in the class. Change the interface to match the class or the class to match the interface and it will stop complaining.

Your interface should be:

```
public interface IBasicListNode<T> {
  /**
   * Returns the current element
   */
  public T getElement();

  /**
   * Gets the next ListNode. Returns null if theres no next element
   */
  public IBasicListNode<T> getNext();

  /**
   * Sets the next ListNode 
   */
  public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node);
}
```

For your next error remember to put

`public` infront of
`public class BasicListNode<t> implements BasicListNodeI<T>`

and

`public interface IBasicListNode<T>`

Comment: I updated my post with a corrected Interface & new(but similar) error

Comment: Updated answer, you forgot to add public to the class AND the interface.

Comment: ok, I will add in the public, which somehow seems to be always left out by the lecturers/teaching staff of my school when they give "skeleton" files, any reason why?

Comment: About the checking will it be something like http://pastie.org/2629109. Then I am thinking I should throw an exception in else? But which one? InvalidArgumentException? Also notice I got an error doing `instanceof BasicListNode<T>` must use `instanceof BasicListNode` are they the same? Why does `public BasicListNode<T> getLast()` work?

Comment: Assuming both your interface and implementing class are in the same package it would in fact work without the public modifier as the when left out it will default to what is sometimes known as package-private and be visible to all within the same package. For details on your other questions please see my post below as I will be adding the answers to that post.

Answer (score 2):

In your interface:

```
public void setNext();
```

in your class:

```
public void setNext(BasicListNode<T> node)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply
You haven't reimplemented method `public void setNext()` without arguments!

If you need it to don't complain, change your interface to declare `setNext` like this

```
public void setNext(BasicListNode<T> node);
```

or implement interface like it is declared ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your interface has the following method:

```
public void setNext(IBasicListNode<T> node);
```

But your class has this one:

```
public void setNext(BasicListNode<T> node) {
```

The contract is thus not respected: the interface method accepts any implementation of `IBasicListNode<T>` as argument, whereas the class method only accepts the specific `BasicListNode<T>` implementation.