# Two Generic Interfaces require each other, how to proper implement them?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I want to use 2 Implementations, but I'm not sure how I should pass each Implementation to each of them. This is what I've got so far:

Interface of A:

```
public interface A<T extends A<T, U>, U extends B<T, U>>{
}
```

Interface of B:

```
public interface B<T extends A<T, U>, U extends B<T, U>> {
}
```

Implementation of A:

```
public class AImpl<T extends B<AImpl<T>, T>> implements A<AImpl<T>, T>{
}
```

Implementation of B:

```
public class BImpl<T extends A<T, BImpl<T>>> implements B<T, BImpl<T>> {
}
```

Now i want to use A and B. I'm not really sure how to implement them. Here is my initial attempt:

Main:

```
//this doesn't work
private AImpl<BImpl> a; 
private BImpl<AImpl> b; 

public main() {
    a = new AImpl<BImpl>();
    b = new BImpl<AImpl>();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes generics makes code simpler, but sometimes it doesnt.  If you rethink your implementation you might find that a simpler solution will work just fine.

Comment: How about `AImpl<AImpl, BImpl>` ? Does this work?

Comment: I'm using this generics because the interface has parameter of itself in getter and setter. My approach is semi based on the figure 1 in this paper http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~blg59/resources/doc/effing-bound-polymorphism.pdf

Comment: Cant't you just say "A" inside the interface?

Comment: With only A, the Implementation doesn't use the same Implementation in every function. That's the problem for me. I tried it and initially it works, but when i pass A which comes from B back to A, errors occur. I can resolve this with casting, but this is not what I want to use. I've got this from this thread [java-interfaces-and-return-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types)

Comment: Just adding the interfaces to a file leads to compiler errors... Are you sure those interface bounds are right? Got raw type warnings and bound mismatch errors

Comment: @user3580294 I fixed the errors, the example should work now.

Comment: Congratulations, your code caused Eclipse to crash :)

Comment: Man, this is bugging me. I know why your code doesn't work, but I can't seem to come up with a way to make it work...

Comment: I found a half bad workaround. I changed to Implementation to pass the other Implementation to the interface instead the interface. After that I could make the Implementations non generics. This makes it possible to use them in main something like that `A<AImpl, BImpl> = a new AImpl();`. This works, but AImpl and BImpl are tightly coupled now.

Comment: Hey OP, one of the Eclipse maintainers might have something that could help: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437087

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance can be far less useful for an interface than a class.

SUGGESTION:
Just refactor and simplify your interfaces so you don't *have* to extend anything but the class itself!

Fewer, smaller interfaces; and shallow inheritance hierarchies for interfaces, are generally a Good Thing.  IMHO...

Comment: While this answer may be correct, to be truly useful and merit a +1 you should at least show an example of what you mean.