# Generics - method return type as extending class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to achieve this in Java 6 :

```
abstract class CurrClass{
    public <T extends CurrClass> T setField (String str) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Compiler complains with **error** : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from CurrClass to T.`

Adding cast works, with **warning** :`"return (T) this;"`

Is there a cleaner syntax to do this? Why is the cast needed?

Comment: Do you want to return `CurrClass` or subclass of it?

Comment: @Tony, A subclass. So, I can say SubClass s = s.setField("");

Comment: Why return the instance you're working on in a set method? Return nothing and keep working. unless this is just for the purpose of the question rather than real code.

Comment: If you're going to return `this` then why is the method defined with a generic type? It should be defined as `public CurrClass setField(String str)`.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau, I am trying to keep the API fluent.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, I wanted to mix some of the inherited setters with CurrClass setters.

Comment: I still don't get why you return the instance at all since it doesn't add anything useful and fluency isn't impacted by not returning the instance unless you create a new instance in your setters... But since this is not in line with the question, I won't discuss this point further.

Comment: @Paddy I'm still not seeing the need for generics here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java interfaces and return types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Method cascading should work on the existing instance.

Comment: @GriffeyDog [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types) sums up my question better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type is more restrictive than the object being returned. That's why the compiler generates the error (and subsequent warning). Consider this scenario:

```
class A extends CurrClass {}
class B extends CurrClass {}

...

A myObject = new B().setField("stringhere");
```

This is perfectly legal in your setup, but will result in a `ClassCastException`.

That's why usually we only return a *more* restrictive type than the signature calls for.

Comment: Hmm.. I had missed that completely.

Comment: @Paddy There's a couple of useful patterns [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2413829/2685386) which might be of use to you

Comment: This seems to be the exact problem I had. Will mark current question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the cast needed?

Because `this` is the CurrClass and the method setField() want to return a extending class of it.

```
Super super = new Sub();   //it's fine, no casting is needed
Sub sub = new Super();     //error!! -->what you do
```

> Is there a cleaner syntax to do this?

If you want to `SubClass s = super.setField("");`, you have to cast.

But we often do `Super s = sub.setField("");` for **[polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)** can bring us convenience.