# Can a java method return value depending upon condition?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a `ICoreClient` interface and `AClient` and `BClient` classes implements this.

`ICoreClient` is exposed for users.

I need to add a new method in `ICoreClient` interface. So, it needs to be implemented in both clients. I can not make this method generic as it has completely different signature but similar functionalities.

I have 2 interfaces `xx` and `yy`

`ClientA` implements `xx` and `ClientB` implements `yy`

So, I decided to add a new `testMethod` in `ICoreClient` that will provide me the instance of `xx` or `yy` depending upon clients.

I want to return the instance of these interfaces from a single method depending upon condition.

**In `ClientA`:**

```
public xx testMethod(){
  return instanceof xx;
}
```

**In `ClientB`:**

```
public yy testMethod(){
  return instanceof yy;
}
```

**What should I write in `ICoreClient` interface?**

```
public zz testMethod()
```

I tried putting a **dummy interface** `zz` (acting as a common supertype) both `xx` and `yy` are implementing this. But still not able to expose methods of `xx` and `yy` in their respective clients as finally it got typecasted in `zz`.

Is there any known approach for this kind of scenario?

**Edit**: If I make return type `Object`, method of these interfaces are not exposed. Although, Object contains the instance of `xx` or `yy`,

User still needs to cast it to (`xx` or `yy` how will user know?) for using the methods in the interface.. I want to expose the methods of the `ClientX` without having to cast to `ClientA` or `ClientB`...

Comment: *I want to return the instance of these interfaces* - You mean instances of *classes which extend this interface* right?

Comment: What you are trying to do seems quite weird to me. I am sure there is a better solution han this one...

Comment: What is `return instanceof xx` supposed to do? This does not look like valid syntax.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types

Comment: Your interface's method needs to return *one type*, and the caller can only use the methods in that type (without casting). Therefore, if you want the caller to be able to call some method on the return value without casting it, that method needs to be in the return type.

Comment: @TheLostMind in java do a class *extend* an interface? Not *implements* it? Weird

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After your edit it looks like you may be looking for [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). You can make your interface like this

```
interface ICoreClient<T>{// T will be set by each class implementing this interface
    T testMethod();
}
```

and each of your classes can look like

```
class ClientA implements ICoreClient<xx>{
    xx testMethod(){
        //return xx
    }
}

class ClientB implements ICoreClient<yy>{
    yy testMethod(){
        //return yy
    }
}
```

Comment: after the edit, the question changed a lot and this seems like a good fit. +1

Answer (score 16):

It is possible only if `xx` and `yy` have a common super type (interface or class). At the worst case, you can always return Object.

```
public Object testMethod () // or a more specific common super type of `xx` and `yy`
{    
    if (..some condition..) {
        return ..instanceof `xx`..;
    } else if (..other condition..) {
        return ..instanceof `yy`..;
    }
    return null; // or some other default instnace
}
```

Comment: `+​l` for common supertype. It pretty much should be that or separate methods.

Comment: problem with this is.. object will contain the instance of `xx` or `yy`.. but user still needs to typecast it for using the methods in the interface.. what OP wants is to expose the methods of the `XClient` without having to typecast..

Answer (score 1):

As returning object means you'll have to cast at the client you could instead return a custom object which contains your possible values:

```
public class MethodResult
{
    private xxx xResult;
    private yyy yResult;
    public MethodResult(xxx xResult){
        this.xResult=xResult;
    }
    public MethodResult(yyy Result){
        this.yResult=yResult;
    }
    public xxx getXResult(){return xResult;}
    public yyy getYResult(){return yResult;}
}
```

and then return this type:

```
public MethodResult testMethod () 
{
    if (..some condition..) {
            return new MethodResult(new xxx());
        } else if (..other condition..) {
            return new MethodResult(new yyy());;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the client can check for which result is not null and use the type accordingly, having access to all the methods defined on xxx or yyy depending on which one is set. Or you could add a method which allows you to check which result was set do make the decision rather than checking for null...