# Java: Reference "own type" in interface

Tags: java, generics, types, clone

I'd like to specify in an interface that an implementing method must return a class of its own type.  For example, the clone method:

```
interface MyArray{
    MyArray clone();
}

interface MyVector extends MyArray{
    // ... 1d-array specific methods
    MyVector clone();
}

class MyDoubleVector implements MyVector{
    //...
    @Override
    public MyDoubleVector clone(){
        //...
        return new MyDoubleVector(Arrays.copyOf(data));
    }
}
```

Now I can call:

```
MyVector vec1 = new DoubleVector(...);
MyVector vec2 = vec1.clone();
```

I want to force all implementers of MyArray to have a clone method that returns the same type as the implementer.  I could save a lot of lines if there were some built-in "meta-type" representing "same type as this class/interface" like:

```
interface MyArray{
    <ArrayOfSameType> clone();
}
```

And not have to redefine the method in extending interfaces in order call the vec1->vec2 clone operation as shown above.

Does Java have some built-in construct for doing this, or is copying and pasting a ton of boilerplate code just the sad fate of a java programmer?

Comment: Welcome to the wacky world of [self-bound type parameters](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394)!

Comment: Ugly code is the sad fate of bad programmers.

Comment: @biziclop A wacky world indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use generics to achieve this

```
interface MyArray<A extends MyArray<A>> {
    A clone();
}

interface MyVector<A extends MyVector<A>> extends MyArray<A> {

}

class MyDoubleVector implements MyVector<MyDoubleVector> {
    //...
    @Override
    public MyDoubleVector clone(){
        //...
        return new MyDoubleVector(Arrays.copyOf(data));
    }
}
```

---

To clarify a point, you need the `extends MyArray<A>` to prevent a developer writing the following.

```
MyArray<Integer> mi = new SomeMyArray<>();
Integer i = mi.clone();
```

This would compile just fine, but clearly should fail at runtime.

Comment: Wait, I just tried and it doesn't work (it still thinks the output of cloning a MyVector should be a MyArray).  However it works fine if I declair MyVector with: `interface MyVector extends MyArray<MyVector> `

Comment: the bound is unnecessary -- it would work the same if declared as `interface MyArray<A>`

Comment: @newacct it would compile, except you could do `Integer i = myArray.clone();` and get a runtime error.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: No, that doesn't make any sense. it will not get a runtime error any more than your code will give a runtime error. If `myArray` is of a type that implements `MyArray<Integer>` and is implemented safely, then it should return `Integer`; why should that cause any runtime error? If `myArray` is of a type that implements `MyArray<SomethingElse>`, then it won't compile.

Comment: @newacct please read my comment again, I didn't mention `MyArray<Integer>` anywhere.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I didn't say you did. I said "if". I was pointing out that No, that code will not cause a runtime error if it compiles, and you did not use raw types or unchecked conversions.

Comment: @newacct and I am telling you it does get a runtime error, which is why it's not a good idea.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: And I am telling you it doesn't. Your statement is meaningless because you did not state what `myArray` is. And if you make `myArray` such that it could cause a runtime error, it wouldn't even compile, or you would need to do something unsafe to get a warning at runtime. The exact same runtime error can be made to happen with your code if those unsafe things are done.

Comment: @newacct I was explaining why the `A extends MyArray<A>` is needed, you don't have to believe me but it does for the reasons I gave.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Programming isn't a matter of "believing". It's a factual subject. You have not given a single valid case where `extends MyArray<A>` is needed. And no, repeating the same thing over and over again does not make it true.

Comment: @newacct I have given you an example, and I could give you many more, but I don't feel like you are listening so I don't see the point.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You have not given an example that can be made any sense of, since you did not define what the thing are in your example. So I can just tell you this: Your example does not compile, therefore, it does not produce a runtime error.

Comment: @newacct that the whole point of doing `A extends MyArray<A>` instead of just `A`, to fail at compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: We are talking about the case of without extends MyArray<A>. You have not given a case that compiles (`myArray` is undefined), and you are saying it causes a runtime error. Declaring something differently cannot cause a runtime error. A class cast exception can happen if you do an unsafe cast or conversion somewhere.

Comment: @newacct So if you happen to not use an unsafe cast, it isn't a problem, but this means the caller needs to know which type the method will return this is at best error prone at best. If you make it clear in the declaration, you don't need to know what type the method actually returns.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Then caller knows exactly what type the method will return -- it's declared to return `A`, and the caller knows what `A` is from the type argument of the compile-time type `myArray`. If the caller doesn't know what `A` is, then even with the bound, the caller doesn't know exactly what type is returned; only that it is a subtype of `MyArray<A>`.

Comment: @newacct correct so if the implementer knows that the type will always be a MyArray then it doesn't make sense to allow the caller to assume its an Integer for example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Nobody is "assuming" anything. If you are "assuming", you are not using generics correctly. The return type is evident from the method declaration and is checked by the compiler. If it compiles and doesn't have warnings, it should be safe. If someone wrote a class `Foo` safely that extended `MyArray<Integer>`, why should its `clone()` method not return `Integer`? Where would a runtime error come from? Why should it not be safe? You are free to write your own implementing class whose type argument is some subtype of `MyArray` if you want; the two do not conflict with each other.

Comment: @newacct I am confused, I though you were advocating that you don't need `extends MyArray<A>` to get it to compile, which is true, but it doesn't check anything, which is the problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: If it compiles, the compiler already checked everything to make sure it's safe. I don't know what further "checking" you are talking about.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You keep saying "clearly would fail at runtime" but that is simply not true. In order for it to fail you must have written some unsafe code that won't compile or will produce a warning or made an explicit cast that isn't safe. You are saying that your hypothetical class (which you have not defined) causes problems; well, that would be because you wrote that class unsafely.

Comment: @newacct I think you are imagining how it should work, in a perfect world, this is what it actually does, using an *implicit* cast, so the developer will not know he/she has done something unsafe, which is why implementer of the API  needs to make sure the type can only be a valid one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Java does not allow you to do "implicit casts" that are unsafe. You must have done an explicit cast somewhere that is unsafe, or you are converting between raw types and parameterized types somewhere. Show the code of this class, and it will have an unsafe cast.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an F-Bound type. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413829/java-interfaces-and-return-types) thread for a similar example.